# Is OAuth2 OBO Grant type supported in Azure AD B2C for MSFT-owned and organization-owned downstream resources?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

Is OAuth2 OBO Grant type supported in Azure AD B2C for MSFT-owned and organization-owned downstream  resources? I was able to get this to work when the downstream resource was one registered in the B2C tenant but not for a MSFT-owned resource like Graph API.
However I have seen posts that suggest that it is entirely unsupported so now not sure.

Answer (score 1):

OBO is not currently implemented in AAD B2C.

Since this is not fully supported, I will not recommend to use it in productions instances until it gets fully implemented on the backend servers.

The workaround represents the “Client Credential” flow for AAD B2C.

Client Credentials is an OAuth grant type that applies to machine-to-machine (M2M) authentications where user interaction is not involved. Services running on the back-end , daemons, sometimes CLIS are all such examples in which they pass along with their Client ID and Client Secret to authenticate themselves, instead of a username + password, and get a token to access resource.

**NOTE**
We just got a new update that the OBO feature for AAD B2C is currently in final testing and PG will be making the announces soon about the feature going in “Preview” for all our customers.

Reference Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

Comment: Hi @ShureshBabu-MT,
how do you get these infos about the roadmap? I'm also waiting for client credentials and obo flow.

Comment: Today, I got an email from Microsoft:
"Regarding your ask on OBO/Client Credential Flow for B2C availability, there is no ETA for it at the moment however we will revert to you once this is available"

Comment: Is there any feedback on when OBO is hitting GA?